# Can we use a panel of some winform from another winform in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I want to use a win-form in C# and display its contents or the whole form in a panel used in another form.

Lets say i have a form A with a panel Panel_of_A
            and a form B with a panel Panel_of_B

I want to display contents of Panel_of_A into Panel_of_B or you may say i want to use Panel_of_A in another form.

Or you may provide help for displaying a form say A into a panel on form B.

Hope i made u understand my thoughts...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think a better way for doing this is to create a User Control which contains that panel and (re)use it on both forms.

Here is a [tutorial how to create User Controls on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Create a user control that contains the logic you want to replicate, then incude the new user control in both places.

Answer (score 2):

How's this for displaying an instance of FormA inside a panel on FormB? The UserControl is probably the better way to go, but what you asked for is possible.

```
fa = new FormA();
fa.TopLevel = false;
fa.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
fa.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 

fb = new FormB();
fb.panel1.Controls.Add(fa); // if panel1 was public

fa.Show();
fb.Show();
```

Comment: What was the problem? I threw together a quick test when I posted the answer and it did work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest defining the panel you want to reuse as a separate class, and place this on both forms. If you need the displayed data to be the same as well, bind to a business object than can be passed between the forms.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size and scale of your application, you may want to consider the (free) [Composite UI Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480450.aspx)

From the blurb:

> It provides proven practices to build
>   complex smart client user interfaces
>   based on well known design patterns
>   such as the Composite pattern, in
>   which simple user interface parts can
>   be combined to create complex
>   solutions, but at the same time
>   allowing these parts to be
>   independently developed, tested, and
>   deployed.